# tfs 2013 pass build variable post build script powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, tfs, build

I am using default build template with TFS 2013 and want to pass the name of the person, who initiated the build, as a variable to a post build powershell script.
I know, that there are a couple of "env:TF_BUILD..." variables, that are filled during build process, but I couldn't find a variable, that holds the "user", who triggered the build.
The variable I am looking for is suppose to be something like "$BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR".

I try to put a -user "$BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR" into section 2.5 as Post-build script arguments in a build definition, but it seems, that it wouldn't be filled or interpreted.

Is there something i have missed or is there an other way to get my problem solved.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The predefined variable "$BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR" is only available for vNext build (TFS 2015 and later version). See [Build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) for details.

For xaml build, there isn't the variable to get the current user who triggered the build within the build process. See [Team Foundation Build environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for details.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. What I wonder, that if I doubleclick on every started build, it says:  <lastname, firstname> triggerd <buildname>. And under my favorite build definitions is listed: <buildname> completed X hours ago <lastname> <firstname>. So the Information must be there. Why don't they put it in a variable to handle the Information in a script.

Comment: @GermanBoy Yeah, Theoretically it should be there, but i check the variables, and try to custom variables as mentioned in [this article](http://prafullakotian.blogspot.sg/2015/05/how-to-define-build-variables-like.html), but can't find a way to pass the value.